# How can I send a checkbox's value when it's checked by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have an event app with a signup form with a list of checkboxes that contain reasons as to why the user wants to sign up for events. On our events page we have a similar signup form, however when signing up on the events page it's already implied they want to attend events, so I want to always pass the "I want to attend events" checkbox value when they signup. Currently, I have it set to it's checked every by default but I'm confused on how to also send that value by default, storing these values in 'reasons'. When submit is clicked, nothing populates for reasons but I always need at least one reason each time

```
  const [reasons, setReasons] = useState([])
```

what happens when a checkbox is checked

```
  const onReasonChange = event => {
    // Remove the reason if already selected
    if (reasons.includes(event.target.value)) {
      setReasons(reasons.filter(reason => reason !== event.target.value))
      return
    }
    // Add the reason
    setReasons([...reasons, event.target.value])
  }
```

the checkbox i'm trying to get to always send the value of

```
    <input
    id="attend"
    type="checkbox"
    value="I want to attend events"
    onChange={onReasonChange}
    checked={reasons.includes("I want to attend events"), 'checked'}
    />
```

Comment: Remove `, 'checked'`.

Comment: FYI both of your `setReasons()` calls should use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to include the default value in your state and have the checkbox be checked is to initialise the state with the default value.

Your state could also work better as a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) if order isn't important

```js
// Saves you repeating string literals
const attendReason = "I want to attend events";

const [reasons, setReasons] = useState(new Set([attendReason]));

const onReasonChange = ({ target: { checked, value } }) => {
  setReasons((prev) => {
    prev[checked ? "add" : "delete"](value);
    return new Set(prev);
  });
};
```

```jsx
<input
  name="attend"
  type="checkbox"
  value={attendReason}
  checked={reasons.has(attendReason)}
  onChange={onReasonChange}
/>
```

[image: Edit focused-sara-qfxu1m]